# Как в название RadioButton изменить цвет опредённого символа? C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравстуйте! У меня есть RadioButton и я в коде ищу в них символ "/". if (radioButton.Content.ToString().Contains("/")
{
И тут мне нужно закрасить этот сивол в другой цвет
}
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать. Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Такое невозможно сделать тем способом, который вы хотите, ибо там скорей всего простая строка, а не лист объектов со своим цветом и прочими параметрами. Хотите сделать это, помещайте внутри кнопки `ItemsControl` допустим, который будет выводит массив классов, а в классе пусть будет статус, либо цвет, ну и сам символ.